# Watson Assistant: How to remove unwanted characters from input string

Tags: regex, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am creating a chatbot where users need to input their phone. I need to be able to clean the user input string, removing any character that is not numeric. How can I do this in IBM Watson Assistant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [string functions like those with regular expressions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#string-extract-string-regexp-integer-groupindex-) to extract the phone number.

Another, maybe even better, option is to define a [pattern-based entity type](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-creating-task). The benefit would be that Watson Assistant could identify parts of the input as phone number entity and you could match dialog nodes or slots for it. If that is not found ("else") you could apply the extraction of numbers and try to guess if that is a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you handle user input at the client side. In your case, use the key-pressed event and an "If statement" to check that the character is  a number (equal or greater than zero). Alternatively you can add the natural language understanding (Easy to configure machine learning service) to Watson Assistant to make it more intelligent. In this case, Watson will be able to know if data is a valid phone number or not.